# Initialize an object with a public variable of another object

Tags: php, oop

Why can I not do this?

```
<?php

class A {}

class B {

    public $a = new A();
}
```

I get :

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use expressions like that when defining properties, but you can set the property in the constructor instead:

```php
class B {
    public $a;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = new A();
    }
}
```

However, this creates a hard dependency for class A.
A better way would be to use interfaces and dependency injection. Something like this:

```php
// Create an interface
interface AInterface {
    // add all required method signatures
}

// Make class A implement that interface
class A implements AInterface {
    // implementations of the methods in the interface
}

// Make class B accept the interface in the constructor
class B {
    public $a;

    public function __construct(AInterface $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

Then when you create the class B, you pass the dependency:

```php
$b = new B(new A());
```

The reason for this is that you can swap out the implementation of class A to some other class as long as it implements the same interface, making it much easier to change implementations and mock your classes (when writing tests etc).

To make the passing in the dependency less cumbersome, you can look into using a
[dependency injection container](https://packagist.org/?query=dependency%20injection%20container).

Comment: Humm... thanks! That is very unfortunate in PHP. In a much larger piece of code I am writing, it would be much more readable if I could write it that way!

Comment: @Fredster - If your classes gets so large that this will make it that less readable, I would suggest rethinking the scope of the class. You might need to break it up into different classes, making sure that each class only single responsibilities. Not saying you _need_ to do that since I don't know what class actually does :-)

Answer (score 0):

With [PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#constructor-property-promotion), there's new constructor semantics for class properties. This may help if you have a large number of properties you want to set, although it does not help with the auto-initialization.

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

class Test {
    public function __construct(
        public A $foo,
        public B $bar,
        public ?C $baz = null
    ) {
        $this->baz = $baz ?? new C;
    }
}

$test = new Test(new A, new B);
```

https://3v4l.org/9DIqq